# iptables dhcp snooping

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, dhcp

I have ubuntu with isc-dhcp-server (DHCP [rfc2131](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt)) as "authoritative" in my local eth, and some user of my local network has activated another dhcp (rogue) that generates conflict

I don't have any Cisco or HP switch with "dhcp snooping" to block dhcp rogue with rules (like a "ip dhcp snooping"). And these rules do not work:

```
localeth=enp2s0
iptables -I INPUT -i $localeth -p udp -m multiport -sports 67,68 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i $localeth -p udp -m multiport -dports 67,68 -j DROP
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i $localeth -p udp -m multiport --dports 67,68 -j DROP
```

```
Ubuntu with 
ISC-DHCP-Server
authoritative;
option wpad code 252
```

How to block this dhcp rogue with iptables rules?. Thanks

**Update:**

As explained [HERE](https://serverfault.com/questions/195131/iptables-allowing-only-a-single-dhcp-relay-client/195181#195181), iptables is not the one indicated for DHCP filtering, but [ebtables](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/), because supposedly "*the Linux tool (ebtables) for filtering at a lower level, of ethernet frames*", therefore this is the rule that I have tried

```
macserver=52:54:00:ee:00:11
ipserver=192.168.1.10
ethserver=enp2s0
ebtables=/sbin/ebtables

$ebtables -A INPUT -i $ethserver --protocol ipv4 --ip-proto udp -s ! $macserver --ip-src ! $ipserver --ip-dport 67:68 -j DROP
```

But doesn't work.

PD: there is a project on github related to this topic called [ebtables-dhcpsnooping](https://github.com/michael-dev/ebtables-dhcpsnooping) but not sure if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your hosts are connected.

If both the "authoritative" DHCP server host and its (supposed-to-be-)client hosts are connected to a "physical"/"dedicated"/"standalone" (hopefully, you know what I mean) switch / "router", then there's not really anything you can do on the DHCP server host, as the other "rouge" DHCP servers does not communicate with the/its clients via the host, but only the switch.

However, if the host is also acting as a switch / "router" by bridging a bunch of Ethernet / L2 (e.g. tap) network interfaces, which are connected to its client hosts. What you should do is to filter on the `FORWARD` chain of `ebtables`:

```
ebtables -A FORWARD --protocol ipv4 --ip-proto udp --ip-dport 67:68 -j DROP
```

(Actually, AFAIK, `68` alone should do.)

The reason that you don't need MAC/IP/interface matching is that, the `FORWARD` chain itself already takes care of that: it applies to traffics going from one bridge port to another bridge port, but not those originate from or target at the bridge host itself.

You probably don't *really* need filtering on either L2 or L3 for the "authoritative" server itself (`INPUT`), unless you also have DHCP client running on it in a *non-interface-specific* manner. It might be worth mentioning that, in case you really want to do it with `ebtables` <strike>(which you don't have to; `iptables` can deal with this case)</strike>, instead of `-i` / `--in-interface`, what you should use is probably `--logical-in`, with the value being the bridge interface itself.

<strike>Btw the quote from the shorewall page hardly makes any sense to me, since ebtables is also part of Netfilter. (It does not even seem to be a grammatically correct sentence.) I suppose what it's trying to say is, iptables does not filter traffics forwarded on L2 (i.e. what goes through a bridge from one of its port to another).</strike>

EDIT: Apparently I was wrong about one thing. I just realized that iptables can block NEITHER inbound NOR outbound DHCP messages. Probably that was what the shorewall quote is trying to say. However, the fact that you CAN block them with ebtables remains true. (Note that ebtables rules will only apply on bridge interfaces, so the `--logical-in` match is optional if there's only one.)

P.S. `"router"` above refers to the fact that, what we call router often consists of a switch as well (i.e. has components that forward on L2 and L3 respectively.)

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Much better than my comment. Everything already makes sense

Comment: @ajcg Just added an `EDIT` to my answer. Take a look if you are interested.

Comment: I already read the correction, but it does not change the meaning is the same. In summary, if there is a hardware net device (switch, etc.) between the firewall linux server and the users, then iptables / ebtables / nftables, etc. can do nothing.